How to get a value from a column from a dataframe if the id is present in multiple columns in another dataframe?
I have 2 dataframes, df1 which are ID numbers of participants (some have more than one ID but is the same person)
df1 <-data.frame(hospid_1=c("A", "B", "C"),
                 hospid_2=c("E", "", "I"),
                hospid_3=c("", "K", ""),
                test = c("jack", "will", "gil"))

and df2 which are results of a blood test with the hospids that correspond to df1 (but in different columns)
df2 <- data.frame(hospid_1=c("A", "I", "K"),
                     Feature=c("123", "456", "789"))

How do I get the test column from df1 matched to the hospids from df2?
The results I would like is
  hospid Feature test
1      A     123 jack
2      I     456  gil
3      K     789  wil

This is a simplified version, I have thousands of hospids in df2 with the master file of df1 that needs matching up. Short of doing it line by line with left_join to each hospid_1/2/3 column, is there a faster and cleaner way?

One way in base R:
rows <- Reduce(
  \(x,y) ifelse(is.na(x), y, x), 
  lapply(df1[sprintf("hospid_%d", 1:3)], \(col) match(df2$hospid_1, col))
)

df2$test <- df1$test[rows]

df2
#   hospid_1 Feature test
# 1        A     123 jack
# 2        I     456  gil
# 3        K     789 will


This worked a treat, thank you! Woudl you be able to tell me what is the code required if my variables were apple_id boy_id cat_id? Same as above to check if the hospid_1 is in any of the apple/boy/cat_id ? I tried with sprintf("%s_id", "apple,boy,cat")] but it doesn't work =(
Thank you in advance

You probably want sprintf("%s_id", c("apple", "boy", "cat")) or skip sprintf() and write directly c("apple_id", "boy_id", ...).

Here is one way to achieve it using pivot_longer function:
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df_key <- df1 %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("hospid_"), values_to = "hospid_1")
left_join(df2, df_key)

Output:
Joining with `by = join_by(hospid_1)`
  hospid_1 Feature test     name
1        A     123 jack hospid_1
2        I     456  gil hospid_2
3        K     789 will hospid_3

